# Hibernate: Prevent update of dirty instances that were never update()'ed manually in the session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I am encountering a behaviour of Hibernate of which I don't know if its a feature or a bug/wrong usage of hibernate in my code.

The FlushMode of my session it set to `FlushMode.AUTO`. If I execute a select query the hibernate autoflush procedure jumps in and tries to update an entity because it thinks that its dirty. However, I am not calling update() for this entity somewhere in my session and I even think I am not modifying it, not even due to cascading. 
The result is that the dirty entity that is automatically updated causes my database to be in an unwanted state. I am tracking this unwanted update of the entity with an SaveUpdate entity listener.

I am gathering all this information from the stacktrace (I show you an excerpt, my above stated theory might be wrong ;))

```
2011-06-24 09:51:07,790 28671957 (SaveUpdateEventListener.java:140) FATAL  - Stacktrace from last unwanted update
java.lang.Exception
    at a.b.dao.listener.SaveUpdateEventListener.checkEntity(SaveUpdateEventListener.java:138)
    at a.b.dao.listener.SaveUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(SaveUpdateEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:997)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    >> at a.b.dao.pricing.PricingDao.list(PricingDao.java:36) << THE SELECT STATEMENT
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    ...
```

So, is the automatic update of dirty fields a feature? If yes, is it caused by FlushMode.AUTO and will I be able to disable this feature with FlushMode.MANUAL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be doing something to the objects in question that make Hibernate perceive them as dirty. Rather than trying to break normal Hibernate behavior, try finding a bug/misusage of Hibernate in your code.

Alternatively, if you absolutely don't need Hibernate session's intelligence for detecting dirty objects and issuing inserts, updates and deletes based on that, consider using Hibernate stateless session.

Comment: Is there a way to see which property exactly was marked as dirty? I've taken a look to the dirty interceptor, but I guess I still will need to know how Hibernate compares the properties

Comment: Your best bet is to reproduce this problem in a very limited session with only a handful of objects in the Hibernate session cache and step through the code. You might want to look at this post: http://blog.xebia.com/2009/04/why-did-hibernate-update-my-database/

Comment: This is probably the apporoach one would go. The problem is that the environment for this is a server under high load and with multiple threads running :/

Comment: @Erik: If you are developing for such deployment, you cannot afford to not have unit tests. If you can reproduce this behavior in a unit test, you can step through the same Hibernate code without even touching your production server.

Comment: Enabling logging of the Hibernate category org.hibernate=TRACE, will show you exactly which properties are dirty (that's how I detect them).